Struct packing in MSVC
Lead-up question to how to correctly interpret this WAVEFORMATEX from decompiled raw bytes?
In this question, a comment made me realize that sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) is not equal to 18, how windows (seem to) expect it.
However, I do not specify the /Zp or the /pack switch and thus the compiler should use the default alignment.
Why is my system reporting sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) = 20?
I am on x86. My compile_commands.json file lists the following :
{
  "directory": "E:\\FOO",
  "arguments": ["D:\\Programme\\Visual Studio 2022\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX64\\x86\\cl.exe", "/c", "/nologo", "/Zi", "/FS", "/Fdbuild\\windows\\x86\\debug\\compile.foo.pdb", "/WX", "/Od", "/std:clatest", "/MTd", "/IFOO", "/DXAUDIO2_HELPER_FUNCTIONS", "/DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN", "/DNOMINMAX", "/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS", "/DCOBJMACROS", "/DCINTERFACE", "/DDO_LOG", "/D_DEBUG", "/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES", "/IE:\\FOO\\build\\.packages\\z\\zlib\\v1.3.1\\55fd28c48bc34b35b89c569e2dd7bcce\\include", "/IE:\\FOO\\build\\.packages\\x\\xaudio2redist\\1.2.11\\163bc5c6e48e49d98ea66f724aede6bf\\include", "/Fobuild\\.objs\\foo\\windows\\x86\\debug\\FOO\\specific\\windows\\dxsound.c.obj", "FOO\\specific\\windows\\dxsound.c"],
  "file": "FOO\\specific\\windows\\dxsound.c"
},

I am compiling for x86_x64 and use the C11 standard.

WAVEFORMATEX MSDN page.
typedef struct tWAVEFORMATEX {
  WORD  wFormatTag;
  WORD  nChannels;
  DWORD nSamplesPerSec;
  DWORD nAvgBytesPerSec;
  WORD  nBlockAlign;
  WORD  wBitsPerSample;
  WORD  cbSize;
} WAVEFORMATEX, *PWAVEFORMATEX, *NPWAVEFORMATEX, *LPWAVEFORMATEX;


Please put the relevant code here.

what code? I am asking why  _STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) == 18); fails, basically.

Please show the WAVEFORMATEX structure. It probably requires 4-byte alighnment.

E.g. if the first member requires 4-byte alignment, the whole structure does, so there will be padding at the end.

WORD is 4 bytes, so the structure needs alignment 4.

@Barmar https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN
Read the warning. I do not specify /Zp. WAVEFORMATEX is a Win32 struct, so I can't change it's alignment

Sorry, I was confused about the sizes of WORD and DWORD.

Since you don't use that option, it's not packing the structure, which means it needs to add padding for alignment.

A simple MSVC (64-bit) program reports 18.

...but if I define an apparently identical struct its size is 20. I can't see any clue in mmeapi.h.

@WeatherVane only if you overwrite natural packing. It is must be 20 bytes

@RbMm I didn't, and I can't see where mmeapi.h does.

...and the definition is enclosed by #ifndef _WAVEFORMATEX_ so it must be defined in windows.h. When I omit #include <mmeapi.h> the program still compiles and runs.

@WeatherVane: The Windows headers usually include <pshpack1.h>. Maybe that's related to the issue OP is experiencing. There are many headers which should not be directly included and likely lack this directive.

@cremno yes, Windows.h is quite small and includes a bunch of other headers.

@WeatherVane: The WAVEFORMATEX docs even say you have to include mmeapi.h and not Mmreg.h where the structure is actually defined. That's very likely the problem.

@cremno Mmreg.h does #include "pshpack1.h". There is no need to include either, only Windows.h.

@WeatherVane i can not view where your mistake, but #include <mmeapi.h > and C_ASSERT(sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)==20);

@RbMm what mistake? The size is 18.

@WeatherVane of course size is must be 20, not 18

@RbMm the size is 18, as shown by a small test program, whether or not I #include <mmeapi.h> which isn't necessary.

@WeatherVane is #include <mmreg.h > it use #pragma pack(push,1) and size is 18, if #include <mmeapi.h > no pack overwrite and size is 20

inside mmreg.h exist #include "pshpack1.h" in the begin and #include "poppack.h" in the end

@RbMm you can't just include mmreg.h without including Windows.h first. And if you do that, there is no need to include any other windows header. I don't get where you are taking this. User cremno already posted similar information. What are you adding?

@WeatherVane - of course i include windows.h too, before, but this is unrelated here.

You're very likely including the wrong header for WAVEFORMATEX.  In the requirements section you can find the correct one. But be careful while the structure is defined in mmeapi.h the header you're supposed to include is Mmreg.h.
So a working minimal example would be:
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmreg.h>

static_assert(sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) == 18);
static_assert(_Alignof(WAVEFORMATEX) == 1);

Vs. an incorrect one:
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmeapi.h>

static_assert(sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) == 20);
static_assert(_Alignof(WAVEFORMATEX) == 4);


Thanks. I had mmreg.h additionally included before windows.h due to automatic header completion. I did not catch that. Thanks!

@Raildex: Good to know. Obviously my answer was just a guess. We don't know which headers and in which order they are included in your source code. So the actual problem may just be similar.

(relying on header order is kinda stupid to begin with tbh)


Why is my system reporting sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) = 20?

The compiler is designed to make the DWORD members four-byte aligned. If the structure starts at a four-byte boundary, all the member in it will be aligned as the compiler is designed to do: The WORD members will be at least two-byte aligned, and the DWORD members will be at least four-byte aligned. This will not be true for the DWORD members if the structure starts at a boundary that is not a multiple of four bytes.
If the structure length were 18 bytes and an array of them were declared, then two adjacent elements in the array could not both start at four-byte boundaries. So the compiler adds two bytes of padding to the end of the array to make the structure size 20 bytes.

Do i need to specify the packing when I want to interface with WIn32 APIs? I doubt I need to change the alignment

@Raildex the Win32 API expects 8-byte alignment on all API structures. What structure packing do the Windows SDK header files expect? /Zp8

@Raildex you not need. with natural (not overwritten) aligment all will be ok. this struct is 4 byte align, and have size 20 bytes. size is always multiple align

@RemyLebeau of course not 8-byte alignment on all API structures. as example WAVEFORMATEX only 4 bytes aligned. wiapi wait natural align, if it not special overwriten with #pragma pack and __declspec(align)
